# Drawback of painters algorithm:

Tags: 3d, graphics, projection, depth-buffer, visualization

We know that to scan convert any polygon first we need to pass any 4 tests of Painter's algorithm.

Suppose I have two polygon S1 and S2, which order is S1->S2.we see that all 4 tests are failed. See the below image where projections on the xy plane is overlapping.[image]
So we need reorder the polygons and tests further whether it will be passed any of the 4 tests or not. After reordering (S2->S1)if we see again 4 tests are failing and xy projection overlapping, it may go into infinite loop. But book says this type of positioned polygon(S1, S2) never go into infinite loop.

My question is where I did mistaken to understand the things? Why after reordering S1,S2 never go into infinite loop if there may be projection overlapping?

Note:[Reference 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b1CeILBiFPijKbpJDrQWNttDFaexMIcf/view?usp=drivesdk)
,[Reference 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bCio22O6ZZ-Q7DiTLhUUsN5CS7IWI48g/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: From your recent series of questions, I get the impression that the book you're trying to learn from might just be not very good, or at least, not a good fit for your needs and learning style. I'd recommend trying to learn from a different source.

Comment: @Dmgregory I am not only following book, I am following different videos etc. But some critical concept not available book, videos. That why I posting this questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But book says this type of positioned polygon(S1, S2) never go into infinite loop.

Does it? The sample you've shown us says:

> **It is possible** for the algorithm just outlined to get into an **infinite loop** if one or more surfaces alternately obscure each other, as in Figure 11. In such situations, the algorithm would continually rearrange the ordering of the overlapping surfaces.
>
> To avoid such loops, we can flag any surface that has been reordered to a farther depth position so that it cannot be moved again. If an attempt is made to switch the surface a second time, we divide it into two parts to eliminate the cyclic overlap. The original surface is then replaced by the two new surfaces, and we continue processing as before.

So, it seems to me that the book specifically calls out that infinite loops are a risk when you have polygons that fail the first test, as shown in the diagram (and all other tests). And it also tells you what to do about it.

If the book elsewhere claims that this infinite loop cannot occur for a specific case, that has not been shown in the excerpts that you've included in your question.

Comment: [see this where infinite loop](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bEIbH1OarVeiGt6a02FmbsTMXLz17gXR/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: you just tell when first all test fails, then we perform reordering, if after reordering again all tests fails of the image posted in question, then what should I do?

Comment: my posted image in question not alternately obscure, so why infinite loop could have been occurring? Please reply, I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: The image in your question might or might not show alternate obscuring surfaces. We cannot tell from this image alone. It could be that although S1 and S2 overlap in screen space, one polygon sits entirely behind the other in depth . Or it could be that S1 and S2 intersect, with say the left corner of S2 poking through the front of S1. If all tests fail a second time then you should follow the directions given in the book: divide the previously re-ordered polygon into two parts. (You could use the other polygon as a cutting plane to ensure one part is fully in front and one fully behind)

Comment: division of surface is recursive process?

Comment: It sounds like you"ve reasoned for yourself that a surface that has been divided once might later need to be divided again. I should emphasize though, we do not use this algorithm in modern games, (we use rasterization with a depth buffer instead) so this site is not a good place to ask about it.